# TypeError: base.valid is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, joi

I am using **Joi** *version:17.6.0*   but it give me the above error.

This is my code.
[image]

**The error which I am facing**
[image]

I am using Insomnia and this is the data which I want to validate.
[image]

Comment: Please post your code and error messages as properly formatted text, not as images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `new Joi.object()` but just `Joi.object()`, it's not a class.